# Error with eXist-db while I am trying to insert data

Tags: java, exist-db

I'm doing a school project which takes ***7584*** rows of a .csv and save it in a .xml file with eXist-db.
Here is my code to insert:

```java
private static Collection collection = ExistConnection.getCollection();
private static XPathQueryService service;

static {
    try {
        service = (XPathQueryService) collection.getService("XPathQueryService", "1.0");
    } catch (XMLDBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```java
public static void insert() {
    App.getCrimes().forEach(crime -> {
        try {
            String insert = "update insert" +
                    "<crime>" +
                    "<date>" + crime.getDate() + "</date>" +
                    "<address>" + crime.getAddress() + "</address>" +
                    "<district>" + crime.getDistrict() + "</district>" +
                    "<beat>" + crime.getBeat() + "</beat>" +
                    "<grid>" + crime.getGrid() + "</grid>" +
                    "<description>" + crime.getDescription() + "</description>" +
                    "<ncicCode>" + crime.getNcicCode() + "</ncicCode>" +
                    "<location>" +
                    "<latitude>" + crime.getLocation().getLatitude() + "</latitude>" +
                    "<longitude>" + crime.getLocation().getLongitude() + "</longitude>" +
                    "</location>" +
                    "</crime>" +
                    "into /crimes";
            service.query(insert);
        } catch (XMLDBException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

And now the code to count the number of crimes:

```java
public static void countAll() {
    try {
        ResourceSet resourceSet = service.query("let $n := count(/crimes/crime) return $n");
        ResourceIterator i = resourceSet.getIterator();
        while (i.hasMoreResources()) {
            Resource r = i.nextResource();
            System.out.println((String) r.getContent());
        }
        ExistConnection.closeCollection();
    } catch (XMLDBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the application I got the next error and the result of count the numbers of crimes:

```
Failed to invoke method queryPT in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XPST0003 unexpected token: $ (while expecting closing tag for element constructor: null) [at line 1, column 171]
Failed to invoke method queryPT in class org.exist.xmlrpc.RpcConnection: org.exist.xquery.XPathException: err:XPST0003 unexpected token: $ (while expecting closing tag for element constructor: null) [at line 1, column 177]
7582
```

I don't know the reason why I only can insert **7582 of 7584** rows.
I tried to delete the rows 7583 and 7584, in case that these rows were wrong for some reason, but the error persists and the count result is 7580.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the .csv, 2 rows had the symbol `<` inside the data and these 2 rows couldn't be added.